# Persist User Control(ASCX) EventHandler Object Across Postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback, ascx

Say that you have a User Control(ASCX):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication1.Test" %>
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" OnClick="test_Click" Text="test" />

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {        
        public event EventHandler Method1;

        public EventHandler Method2
        {
            get { return (EventHandler)Session[this.ClientID + "|Method2"]; }
            set { Session[this.ClientID + "|Method2"] = value; }
        }

        public EventHandler Method3
        {
            get { return (EventHandler)ViewState["Method3"]; }
            set { ViewState["Method3"] = value; }
        }

        protected void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Method1 != null)
                Method1(this, e);

            if (Method2 != null)
                Method2(this, e);

            if (Method3 != null)
                Method3(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And you have a page that you place that UserControl on:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Test.ascx" TagName="Test" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <uc1:Test ID="TestControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="Result" runat="server" Text="Test" />
</asp:Content>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Uncomment each one to observe their behavior

            //Will never trigger(unless reset on each postback)
            //if (!IsPostBack) TestControl.Method1 += new EventHandler(Test);

            //Will trigger(the code will run) but makes no change to the parent page
            //if (!IsPostBack) TestControl.Method2 += new EventHandler(Test);

            /*
            Will fail because it can't serialize the "EventHandler" object
            You can play around by changing this to a delegate type 
            and making that serializable, but that fails as well  
            */
            //if (!IsPostBack) TestControl.Method3 += new EventHandler(Test);
        }
        protected void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Result.Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But for this given User Control we want to define an event to capture a button's click and have that trigger the event of the User Control's parent's choosing. Also due to requirements outside of the scope of this example, say that we would like to only ever set the value of the "MethodX" EventHandler once, ie not recreate the control/property on every Postback(in this example I demonstrate this concept by only setting the event once on the page load).

How can this be accomplished? All three methods that I've attempted fail in there own unique ways... I've so far not found a similar question related to the persistence of events, most posts deal with variable/object persistence("Use the ViewState" or various other ways of persisting non-event objects, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409218/do-asp-page-variables-not-persist)) or simply direct the user to "recreate the control on every Postback(including related properties)", see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410475/eventhandler-is-null).

Any feedback or insight would be helpful, especially confusing to me is the behavior of "Method2", I think I don't have a full enough understanding of the page life-cycle to understand why that's occurring.

Comment: A control is built during initialization and destroyed once rendered - I would not recommend persisting it.  However, you can store the state of the control using ViewState["State"] = "SOMETHING TO RELOAD TESTCONTROL METHOD" and that state variable can be used to reattach the event handler of your choice.

Comment: @BrianMains Interesting, so are saying that I can use Viewstate "State" property in the parent page to store the the entire User Control, and that will allowing me to persist the EventHandler Property set within that state, or is the "State" property used within the control itself to preserve its own state or the state of the EventHandler? Do you know of any examples of where this has been done(maybe an example of this would clarify the suggestion)?

Comment: No, ViewState can't store the control; put the control on the page, and then use viewstate to retain some flags to control whether the UC shows/hides and which event handlers should get attached, etc...  It controls true/false values that say whether to show or hide the control, but doesn't store the control directly.  UC's have viewstate too, so you can store settings in the UC in its own viewstate container.

Comment: @BrianMains O yes now I understand where your going, you mean to suggest that I use some sort of string(e.g. flag) to control which event will be fired via external logic in the ASPX that implements the UC, well I guess that would be one way to go about that but its not truly event persistence as you would still need to implement some logic in the parent page to understand what that flag means and what to do with it,  anyways thank you for the suggestion, I very much appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You need to register events before load event (try on init). Click event triggering happens between init and load events.</del>

<del>UPDATE: Sorry, you're right click event is raised between Load and LoadComplete.</del>

**UPDATE**: I think I found what you need and, disappointingly, it cannot be posible what do you want. An instance delegate of a non-static method is strongly dependent of the instance from the method's class. Every request, the instance of the page is created, and when the request's end, it's disposed. Pages aren't singleton instances. This is the reason why, even if you store the handler in the session, it cannot be reused, because it's trying to call a method from a disposed instance.

This is a good article about how events and delegates works: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

The most important part is this:

> [..] the key points of data in any particular delegate instance are the method the delegate refers to, and a reference to call the method on (the target). For static methods, no target is required.

That *target* is the page/usercontrol instance of the page the first moment you created. When you are doing a Postback, the page/usercontrol instance changed, but your persisted handler's *target* not.

Comment: According to the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the click event of the button in the control occurs between the "Load" and "LoadComplete" events, this is consistent with the behavior experienced while debugging the control(when the event is set on every postback). Assigning a event to the User Control before the Load method(while implementing "Method1" of the User Control) doesn't solve the EventHandler persistence issue. Do you have an example of this working? Maybe if you included some code I could better understand your solution.

Comment: Sorry, you're right! Still, I don't understand why you require that an event handler cannot be registered every postback. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Good question, look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998186/how-to-persist-user-control-values). This problem presents itself with not just standard objects but with events, typically to overcome this issue you can take these approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646533/how-do-you-persist-a-class-on-postback-in-an-asp-net-3-5-web-forms-project), well for events none of those approaches work, I must "register an event handler" every postback, not elegant... This questions is about finding a more elegant/cleaner way, but I'm not sure its possible.

Comment: Why is _unelegant_ to register every postback an event handler? You can do it in the aspx: `<uc:Test runat="server" OnMethod1="test_Click" />`. I don't see this code unelegant at all :S

Comment: You assume that the method remains static. I've had several instances(one of which prompted this question) where I've wanted to change that method based on complex set of conditions, and weather you have a flag inside in the control as @BrianMains suggested, or if you maintain that logic outside the method, somehow between postbacks you need to track which method should be triggered for that control and then reassign it each and every time. So I guess in the static context you are correct its not an issue, but in a dynamic context I would still maintain that it is unelegant.

Comment: But in a dynamic context is better to do that complex logic inside the handler, and then call the _real_ method you want to call. At least is what I would do. And, in the worst case, persist in Viewstate a mark about what class you want to call in postback (like an Enum or string) and use it in the handler.

Comment: Yes you could do that, or you could maintain a state as @BrianMains suggested, or you could simply reevaluate the complex logic every postback. But what its seems you cannot do is simply dynamically assign an event to the control and forget about it, which seem to me structurally the simplest solution(though I guess this is a matter of opinion). So this questions really is more of a "can it be done" vs "what are my alternatives".

Comment: But you don't want to persist _the handler_. You want to persist _the function that binds the handler with the event_. That's pretty crazy.